# .findOne function, trying to have multiple params

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

My .findOne function seems to work how it should, I think I'm missing something though. It displays the accounts that have the Username I put in, but it completely ignores the Password field.

```
exports.accountLogin = (req, res) => {
   Accounts.findOne({Username: 'Test', Password: 'Password'}, (err, account) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(account)
    });
```

Here is my Accounts Schema

```
const AccountsSchema = new Schema({
    Username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 8,
    },
    Password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 10, 
    },
    AccountType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 100, 
    },
    Email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 35, 
    },
    Age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        max: 100, 
    },
    Question1A: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 100, 
    },
    Question2A: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 100, 
    },
    Question3A: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 100, 
    },
});
};
```

Comment: Your query seems to be fine. can you show `Accounts` collection schema.

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal I just added my Accounts schema